# find number of rows in a paginated table in Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a grid with multiple pages each page has 10 rows, I need to get the number of the total rows in this page, how can I do that in webdriver using java?

Comment: Post the code tried by you and also page screeshot or HTML code so that I can help you better.

Comment: @SarojPurbey Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider suggesting OP to update the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thank You @DebanjanB . I will definitely consider that in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class = 'k-widget k-grid k-reorderable']")); 
int rowcount = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr[class='k-alt']")).size();
```

Comment: Could you please share your html.so that others can help you with particular answer.